# Currency sign label showing the wrong value using Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, applet

The currency label is meant to display "£" if the currency value is equal to GBP and if not, display the "€"sign. However, it's returning the "$" sign no matter if the currency is GBP or EURO. Why?

```
NSString *currencySign = [overviewModel.currency isEqualToString:@"GBP"] ? @"£" : @"€";
self.productCoreDetailView.priceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", currencySign, overviewModel.price];
self.productCoreDetailView.priceVATLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", currencySign, overviewModel.price_vat];
```

Comment: Whats your overviewModel.currency returning?

Comment: @ParasGorasiya By default it returns "GBP"

Comment: Print overviewModel.currency before assigning it to currencySign.

Comment: @ParasGorasiya  2017-08-07 09:57:27.127718+0100 CVP.com[8738:3461486] CURRENCY IS : GBP, it's GBP but it returns $ sign again, if I create a separate label it displays the correct sign, but when its in the price label it displays the $ sign

Comment: In that case you might be setting self.productCoreDetailView.priceLabel.text = @"$" somewhere in code after setting it to what you want. So check whether you are setting it to "$" after this code.

Comment: @ParasGorasiya Yes, just figured out what was wrong ..... I made the most stupid mistake possible, there was a $ label covering it. thank you anyway..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing this manually, why not use the NSNumberFormatter instead?

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;
formatter.currencyCode = @"GBP";
NSString *formattedNumber = [formatter stringFromNumber:@23.50];
// formattedNumber = £23.50
```

Or Swift

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .currency
formatter.currencyCode = "EUR"
let formattedNumber = formatter.string(from: 23.50)
// formattedNumber = €23.50
```

By using NSNumberFormatter you will be able to support any currency and simplify your code.

Comment: Create an NSDecimalNumber from the string and use that. NSDecimalNumber is a type specifically for working with values that can't loose precision so is perfect for monetary values. ```NSDecimalNumber *number = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:@"23.50"];```

Comment: 2017-08-07 10:48:37.043673+0100 CVP.com[8782:3476122] jello£290.83
That's what it gets printed but the pound sign doesn't get displayed in the label and I have no idea why it's doing that

Comment: nvm... I was overriding it, it works perfectly thanks